# How to customize Facebook sharer text dynamically

Tags: facebook, share

I need to change dynamically the content of Facebook sharing application. I want to share a game through this application. The goal is to display score and time passed in game where the website description is supposed to be.

[image]

In this image we have "Social plugins let you see what your friends have liked, commented on or shared on sites across the web." as text. I would like to display something like "Your score is 812 and you passed 30 secondes in game" instead.

Is that possible?

****EDIT****

Ok then, if it's too complicated (and out of budget) to write something like that, is it possible to change the user input dynamically, I mean the "Say something about this" field??

[image]

Comment: Use og-tags on your website

Comment: The problem with og tags is that they are static, I cannot change text depending on user score in game..

Comment: You can, if you create an individual URL to share for the user and their score …

Comment: If you want to share score you should look at the score API instead

Comment: @WizKid, the score API approach seems interesting. Can I use it even if the game is not a facebook game? Actually it's a simple javascript game.

Comment: _“is it possible to change the user input dynamically, I mean the "Say something about this" field?”_ – you can not change that placeholder, and you are not allowed to post any message that was not a 100% created by the user. If your app is not a game (so you can not use the score API), your best solution is what I already said: Create individual URLs for user’s results/scores/whatever, using GET parameters, and provide the relevant OG meta data under those URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @CBroe comment, I managed to change the text dynamically this way:

Link for sharing:

```
<a id="facebook-share" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?&p[url]=http://www.example.com/index.php?score=56&amp;timed=17" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
```

Then in the index page, I changed the og meta tags dynamically, by doing something like that:

```
<?php

        $score = $_GET["score"];
        $time = $_GET["timed"];

        if($score==''){
            print '<meta content="http://www.example.com" property="og:url">';
            print '<meta content="Example" property="og:title">';
            print '<meta content="Description Example" property="og:description">';
        }else{
            print '<meta content="http://www.example.com/index.php?score='.$score.'&amp;timed='.$time.'" property="og:url">';
            print '<meta content="Example" property="og:title">';
            print '<meta content="you win '.$score.' points  in '.$time.' secondes" property="og:description">';
        }

?>
```